# xcode: background full screen with storyboard

Tags: xcode, swift, storyboard, imageview

I have A few problems.
I hope someone can solve my doubts.
Please answer me in a very simple way because I don't know English very well and I'm a base level for app ios.
I would like TO add a background full screen in width for iphone and ipad.
I work with storyboard.

1. is it better that I use universal (1x, 2x, 3x) or that I specify all devices: iphon (1x, 2x, 2x retina, 3x) and ipad (1x, 2x)?
2. I don't understand the correct pixel dimension. I saw different documents 
   but I don't understand because for 2x there are different dimensions... and 
   then what is the dimension correct? And the resolution in dpi?
   Please type me correct  dimension  for all devices and how I have to put it 
   into xcassets
3. when I open xcode... I insert UIImageview and I fix to 0 the margins... 
   then I insert another UIImageview that I fix to 0 the right, left and top 
   margin and then I center the last imageView and I insert my background 
   selecting "Aspect fill"... is it correct?
4. My background has a circle ON the left and I want center in this circle a 
   label.
   How can I do?

Thanks for all
Chiara

Comment: These are four separate questions, you should ask them individually with as much detail as you can :)

Comment: it is true but for me is one question because I put my background in my app and I must know all this